# ListBox List<T> binding issue when removing item

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, compact-framework, listbox

I'm having trouble with a `ListBox` control that has a List of objects binded to it.

I'm calling this function each time I add or remove an object to/from the list:

```
private void RefreshBarList()
{
   lstBar.DataSource = null;
   lstBar.Items.Clear();
   lstBar.DisplayMember = "BarDescription";
   lstBar.DataSource = BarCollection.BarList;
   lstBar.Refresh();
}
```

It works well when adding items to the list or removing anything but the last item in the list. If i remove the last object in the list it will display in the listbox the object types and not the **BarDescription**.

BarCollection is another class that contains a List with Bar objects and BarCollection.BarList returns exactly that list.

The **Bar** class is very simple:

```
public class Bar
{
   private string _barDescription;

   public string BarDescription
   {
      get
      {
         return _barDescription;
      }
   }

   public Bar(string barDescription)
   {
      _barDescription = barDescription;
   }
}
```

I cannot figure out why this happens, does anyone have any suggestions? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which Compact-framework are you referring to?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't binding it anywhere else?

Comment: If you remove the last item in the list, what are you expecting to be displayed? There's nothing in the list, there is no object with property BarDescription available. This sounds like the default behavior for binding an empty object, as only the signature (but no data) is available.

Comment: I'm not binding it anywhere else. The method RefreshBarList gets called both when i'm adding or when i'm removing an item from the list. The only time the biding gets messed up is when you remove the last object in the list.

Comment: @jamietre:  There could be 6 items in the list:
-Works fine if you remove the 4th
-It shows object type in the list instead of the property BarDescription for the remaining 5 items if you remove the 6th(which is last)

Comment: Oh - do you mean if the object that is removed happens to be the last one? I thought you meant "when I remove the last one remaining."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) instead of a `List<T>`

Comment: +1: I blogged about resolving this exact problem back in September 2008 - see http://www.nichesoftware.co.nz/blog/200809/databinding-lists

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, only put ToArray() in mylist and solved the problem.